# jQuery open, close div on blur and on click

Tags: jquery

Hey Guys I made a search but couldn't find an answer. It is very basic at first look, or may be it is really basic :).

I want to click on a.search and it should open `$('#search-input')` and I want to click anywhere on the page but the `$('#search-input')` to close the search box. My code below does not work. When you click on the a.search it closes and opens again.

I tried unbinding and binding again, but does not work. Please help:)

```
 searchHeader = 'closed';
 $('a.search').on('click', function(e) {
   if (searchHeader == 'closed') {
       $('.header-search').stop(true).fadeTo(100, 1);
       $searchInput.focus();
       searchHeader = 'open';
        status = '1';
        return false;
    } else {
        $('.header-search').stop(true).fadeTo(0, 1);
        $searchInput.focus();
        searchHeader = 'closed';
        status = '0';
        return false;
    }
});
$searchInput.on('blur', function() {
    $('.header-search').stop(true).fadeTo(0, 0).css("display", "none");
});
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking but here it is
<a href="" class="search">Search</a>
<div class="header-search"> <input class="search-Input" ></div>

Answer (score 0):

No need of Binding and unbinding. you just need to trigger the Document Click event and on click event you can write your code.

Comment: But then clicking on the search input will hide the div. Because you are clicking on the document, correct? Then user can't type in search box.

Comment: Yes right Hakan ! But in that case you can customize your function and fetch the Id of that search box and in that case you can skip your hide code. 

here is sample -
function Hide(e)
{
        if(e.Id != $("#searchbox").id)
               $("#searchbox").hide();
}

Comment: If I m not mistaken when you listen an event on document such as click then your click id is always the .parent of all. in this case I have an id in body tag and my click event always alerts that id.  In other words function Hide(e)... that e will not give me the clicked id. Please correct me if I am mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

```
bindEvents: function() {
    enter code hereinternalSearch.searchInput = $('#search-input');
        var $searchInput = internalSearch.searchInput;
        $status = '';
        $('a.search').on('click', function(e) {
            if ($('.header-search').is(':hidden')) {
                $('.header-search').stop(true).fadeTo(100, 1);
                $searchInput.focus();
                $status = 'open';
            }

            $(document).on('click', function(e) {
                if ($(e.target).attr('id') != 'search-input') {
                    if ($status == 'closed' || $status == 'undefined') {
                        if ($('.header-search').is(':visible')) {
                            $searchInput.blur();
                            $('.header-search').stop(true).fadeTo(0, 0).css("display", "none");
                            $(document).off('click');
                        }
                    }
                }
                $status = 'closed';
            });

            e.preventDefault();
        })
```

Comment: For now I came up with this please let me know if there is more elegant way.